# Broan fan and light no longer function

Tags: wiring

SOLVED. It was secret door number 3. In this case, a GFI outlet two floors down in the basement adjacent to the fuse panel. Having only been in the house a couple months I never even noticed it or thought of it as playing a key role in a bathroom fan/light  two floors up.

Our Broan fan and light combo in the bathroom no longer work -- both fan and light are non-functional.  I noticed that the GFI plug wasn't working.  Upon pressing test/reset I heard it buzzing and it smelled like something burned inside of it. As a result I removed the outlet and replaced it.

Once the GFI was replaced it now functions correctly, but fan and light combo overhead are still not working.  Is it possible that the fan AND the light stop working at the same time.

Anything else worth checking?

Model number is 678g/2678F-A

Wires didnt look damaged, but that was just visual inspection.

I took the cover off to get model number and see that the fan and light plug in like a normal outlet. No voltage from those outlets and the light works when plugged into another outlet. So, seems the issue exists between the switch and the hard wiring of the fixture perhaps.

Wiring was just as on old switch.

[image]

Comment: What make and model is the fan/light combo? Have you checked in the GFCI box for damaged wiring?

Comment: We need a picture of his you hooked up the new gfci  receptacle

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: While you've got it open with the power off, take a bit of sandpaper and scrape the paint off those wires.  The part of the wire that goes under the screw should never have any paint on it; it needs to be bare copper in contact with the screw.

Comment: Glad you were able to lick it!  If you could post your update as an answer, I'll give you a +1 for it :)

Answer (score 1):

[Posted for original questioner]

SOLVED. It was secret door number 3. In this case, a GFI outlet two floors down in the basement adjacent to the fuse panel. Having only been in the house a couple months I never even noticed it or thought of it as playing a key role in a bathroom fan/light two floors up.